# Query a table for unique on one column and return all columns

Tags: sql, unique

```
table_name
-----------------
ID [PK]
Title 
Last_Name 
First_Name 
Middle_Name 
Suffix 
Full_Address 
Address1 
Address2 
City 
State 
Zip 
County 
Phone1 
Phone2 
Email
```

I have a table with the above column names.  I want to be able to return all columns and all rows in a query where "Email" is unique.  How would I do this with SQL?

If two rows have the same email address then I want only one of those rows returned.  It does not really matter which.  If I could combine the rows that would be great be not necessary.

I am using LibreOffice Base which is a .odb database which uses the HSQL Database Engine.

I am trying to select only rows whose emails are not duplicated in the table.  An example is I want to email every person in the database but I know that many people are listed in the database twice because I have combined data from several different sources.

My primary key is the ID column which I just see now I did not list above.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? For example, if two rows have the same email address, do you only want one of those rows and you don't care which? Also, please identiy the RDMS you are using; some databases may have different possible solutions. And just edit your question; dont' answer in a comment. Welcome to SO!

Comment: What type of database are you using?  Is LibreOffice Base the DB, or is it just a front-end tool to access another database (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc)?

Comment: What column is your primary key? Do you have an auto-incremented column or date_created column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution to get only one row per email (regardless of whether or not it has duplicates). The row is based on the maximum value for `ID` for each email:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM   (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM table_name GROUP BY Email) a
JOIN   table_name b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

For phone number:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM   (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM table_name GROUP BY Phone1) a
JOIN   table_name b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: This code returned the same amount of records 309 as the sql above.  Some kind of issue in my data do you think?  I have over 30000 records that should return over 10000+ unique emails.

Comment: @ToddWelch, can you clarify: Are you trying to select only rows whose emails are not duplicated in the table, or are you just trying to select one row per email, regardless of whether that email has other duplicates or not? Also please address the question I posed in the question comments: *What is your primary key column* ?

Comment: I am trying to select only rows whose emails are not duplicated in the table.  An example is I want to email every person in the database but I know that many people are listed in the database twice because I have combined data from several different sources.

My primary key is the ID column which I just see now I did not list above.

Comment: One other part to this, lets say I want to grab every row that has a unique Phone1 OR Phone2?

Comment: @ToddWelch, do you mean the combination of phone1 and phone2 should be unique?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SQL engine that supports window functions, then you would do:

```
select Title Last_Name, First_Name, Middle_Name, Suffix, Full_Address, Address1,
       Address2, City, State, Zip, County, Phone1, Phone2, Email
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by email) as NumOnEmail
      from t
     ) t
where NumOnEmail = 1
```

In any database, you should be able to do:

```
select Title Last_Name, First_Name, Middle_Name, Suffix, Full_Address, Address1,
       Address2, City, State, Zip, County, Phone1, Phone2, Email
from t
where t.email in (select email from t group by email having count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: Your second query worked but it only returned around 300 rows when I know that it should return over 10,000 unique email addresses.

Comment: What do you mean by unique email addresses?  This query returns email addresses that have exactly one record.